# Как скрывать другие спойлеры, когда открываешь один?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я могу открывать и закрывать каждый спойлер независимо от других. Как сделать чтобы одновременно активным был только один спойлер? Иными словами, как изменить мой код для логики аккордеона?

```js
const spoiler = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

spoiler.forEach(function(index) {
    index.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');

        let content = this.nextElementSibling;

        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        }
        else
        {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container
{
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 110, 0.25) 0px 5px 30px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;

    padding: 10px 20px;

    font-size: 14px;
}

.item + .item {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.title.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
}

.title:before,
.title:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    background: #000;
    display: block;
}

.title:before
{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    right: 24.5px;
}

.title:after
{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    right: 20px;
}

.content
{
    opacity: 0;
    user-select: none;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: .3s max-height;
    background-color: white;
}

.content p {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.title.active ~ .content
{
    opacity: 1;
}

.title.active:before
{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 2px;
}

.title.active:after
{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem suscipit minus unde accusantium minima voluptates quisquam. Perspiciatis, officiis excepturi aliquid exercitationem culpa in, vero quisquam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, atque ratione maxime aspernatur a. Recusandae minus sunt blanditiis voluptate cum velit ipsum non placeat quibusdam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore iure consequuntur nostrum quibusdam odit, deserunt aliquid ratione maiores eos consectetur natus omnis dolorum mollitia totam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А что с вашим кодом не так?

Comment: Открывались все спойлеры, поочередно, теперь же открытым может быть только один.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы добиться нужного поведения блоков, достаточно осуществлять их перебор с удалением класса `.active`, а у того, который в данный момент был нажат - **переключать** класс:

```js
const spoiler = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

spoiler.forEach(function(index) {
  index.addEventListener('click', function() {
    spoiler.forEach((el) => {
      let content = el.nextElementSibling;
      if (el != this) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
        el.classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.style.maxHeight ? null : content.scrollHeight + 'px';
        this.classList.toggle('active');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 110, 0.25) 0px 5px 30px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item+.item {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.title::before,
.title::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 7px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}

.title::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  right: 24.5px;
}

.title::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 20px;
}

.title.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
}

.title.active::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  height: 2px;
}

.title.active::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 2px;
}

.content {
  opacity: 0;
  user-select: none;
  padding-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 0.3s max-height;
  background-color: white;
}

.title.active~.content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.content p {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem suscipit minus unde accusantium minima voluptates quisquam. Perspiciatis, officiis excepturi aliquid exercitationem culpa in, vero quisquam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, atque ratione maxime aspernatur a. Recusandae minus sunt blanditiis voluptate cum velit ipsum non placeat quibusdam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">
      <p>Title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore iure consequuntur nostrum quibusdam odit, deserunt aliquid ratione maiores eos consectetur natus omnis dolorum mollitia totam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да именно так и хотел, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Ты вот такой результат хотел получить?

```js
const spoilers = document.querySelectorAll('.title');

        const container = document.querySelector('.container');

        container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            const target = e.target.closest('.title');
            if (target.classList.contains('active')){
                target.classList.remove('active');
                let content = target.nextElementSibling;
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            }else{
                    spoilers.forEach(function(splr) {
                        splr.classList.remove('active');
                        let content = splr.nextElementSibling;
                        content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    });
                    target.classList.add('active');
                    let content = target.nextElementSibling;

                    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                        content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
                    }
            }
            
        })
```

```css
body
{
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container
{
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: rgba(100, 100, 110, 0.25) 0px 5px 30px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;

    padding: 10px 20px;

    font-size: 14px;
}

.item + .item {
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.title.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
}

.title:before,
.title:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 7px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    background: #000;
    display: block;
}

.title:before
{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    right: 24.5px;
}

.title:after
{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    right: 20px;
}

.content
{
    opacity: 0;
    user-select: none;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: .3s max-height;
    background-color: white;
}

.content p {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.title.active ~ .content
{
    opacity: 1;
}

.title.active:before
{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    height: 2px;
}

.title.active:after
{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem suscipit minus unde accusantium minima voluptates quisquam. Perspiciatis, officiis excepturi aliquid exercitationem culpa in, vero quisquam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus, atque ratione maxime aspernatur a. Recusandae minus sunt blanditiis voluptate cum velit ipsum non placeat quibusdam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="title">
                <p>Title</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore iure consequuntur nostrum quibusdam odit, deserunt aliquid ratione maiores eos consectetur natus omnis dolorum mollitia totam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: а что за ошибки?

Comment: Вы уже исправили.